Clarifications on Smith Normal Form
I'm solving an exercise where I need to find the Smith normal form of a matrix. As I understood, what I need to do for a $2\times3$ matrix is to find the determinant of each of its $1\times1$ and $2\times2$ minors, find the GCDs and putting the results of the subsequent divisions of the various GCDs in the diagonal of the matrix, and in the $2\times3$ case the last column will be all zeros.
The matrix in question is $\begin{pmatrix} 22 & 24 & 2 \\ 22 & 42 & 20 \end{pmatrix}$. Obviously the GCD of all $1\times1$ minors is $2$, so it will be the $(1,1)$ entry of the matrix. For the $(2,2)$ entry I need to compute the $2\times 2$ minors determinants, which are all equal to $396$. So in the $(2,2)$ spot there would be $396/2=198$.
I have two questions about this:

Is the reasoning correct here? Is the fact that the last column is a linear combination of the first two relevant in any way?

Is the composition the same if we consider the coefficients to not just be simply integers, but if we consider the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ by the ideal generated by powers of prime numbers, like $S=\{2^n, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$? Because I believe that the classes of integers I'm working with here isn't impacted by the localization, since equivalent classes in the localization are nothing but "fractions which I haven't simplified yet"?


Thank you in advance.

Why not use row/column operation to put the matrix in Smith Normal Form? That will give you the invariant factors as 2 and 198 as you say, but it will also (if you keep track of things) give you bases of $\mathbb Z^2$ and $\mathbb Z^3$ with respect to which the matrix becomes that diagonal.

I didn't know about using minors to calculate Smith Normal Form. I know about row/column operations, but it sounds like a plausible method. Regarding localizations, I think what happens with the $S$ you gave is that it lets you divide out the factors of $2$, so you are left with $1$ and $99$ down the diagonal.

The columns of a $2\times3$ matrix are always linearly dependent, so I wouldn't read too much into the 3rd column being dependent on the 1st two.

@KyleMiller I was thinking that, so is it because the ideal generated by (2) and (198) is the same as the one generated by (1) and (99) because 2 is invertible?

@GerryMyerson Of course, I don’t know why I didn’t think of that, thank you!

Working over the integers, $2$ is not invertible, and the ideal generated by $(2)$ and $(198)$ does not contain $1$.

Yes I was thinking about the localization over the $S$ I wrote in the original question.
